# css hover effect height in list item

Tags: javascript, html, css, sass

I only want the hovered element to be affected by its height. But all row items increase in height. What can i do to increase the height of the element that is just hovered ? (If there is a solution with javascript, it will be too)

HTML and CSS codes:

```css
.names {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
}

.names div {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  padding: 16px 0;
  text-align: center;
}

.names div a {
  font-size: 16px;
  color: #25282e;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.names div a:hover {
  font-weight: 700;
}

.names div a:hover~img {
  display: block;
}

.names div img {
  width: 40px;
  margin-top: 16px;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="names">
  <div><a class="name" href="#">Name</a><img src="https://picsum.photos/seed/picsum/200/300"></div>
  <div><a class="name" href="#">Name</a><img src="https://picsum.photos/seed/picsum/200/300"></div>
  <div><a class="name" href="#">Name</a><img src="https://picsum.photos/seed/picsum/200/300"></div>
  <div><a class="name" href="#">Name</a><img src="https://picsum.photos/seed/picsum/200/300"></div>
  <div><a class="name" href="#">Name</a><img src="https://picsum.photos/seed/picsum/200/300"></div>
  <div><a class="name" href="#">Name</a><img src="https://picsum.photos/seed/picsum/200/300"></div>
  <div><a class="name" href="#">Name</a><img src="https://picsum.photos/seed/picsum/200/300"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure of the exact layout you want, but in general just add `position: absolute` to the images on hover.  e.g.

```css
.names {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
}

.names div {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  padding: 16px 0;
  text-align: center;
}

.names div a {
  font-size: 16px;
  color: #25282e;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.names div a:hover {
  font-weight: 700;
}

.names div a:hover~img {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.names div img {
  width: 40px;
  margin-top: 16px;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="names">
  <div><a class="name" href="#">Name</a><img src="https://picsum.photos/seed/picsum/200/300"></div>
  <div><a class="name" href="#">Name</a><img src="https://picsum.photos/seed/picsum/200/300"></div>
  <div><a class="name" href="#">Name</a><img src="https://picsum.photos/seed/picsum/200/300"></div>
  <div><a class="name" href="#">Name</a><img src="https://picsum.photos/seed/picsum/200/300"></div>
  <div><a class="name" href="#">Name</a><img src="https://picsum.photos/seed/picsum/200/300"></div>
  <div><a class="name" href="#">Name</a><img src="https://picsum.photos/seed/picsum/200/300"></div>
  <div><a class="name" href="#">Name</a><img src="https://picsum.photos/seed/picsum/200/300"></div>
</div>
```

To note I've also added `margin-top: 20px` just for stylistic purposes, it isn't required.

Comment: I am not sure that adding `position: absolute` is necessary. yes, it may work but without giving the divs some height (check my answer) the image will overlap the divs below on hover. and when giving those divs height (for this example) you don't need to add the `position: absolute`.
If I am missing something I would love to hear your thoughts about it.

Comment: @TamirAbutbul my presumption was they should overlap, like most menus do. Without the OP specifying though it is a moot point.

Comment: well ye, the desired layout is not 100% clear from the question

Answer (score 0):

One thing you can do is give your items height.

I edited the`.names div` selector by adding  `height:30px;` for example

```css
.names {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
}

.names div {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  padding: 16px 0;
  height:30px;
  text-align: center;
}

.names div a {
  font-size: 16px;
  color: #25282e;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.names div a:hover {
  font-weight: 700;
}

.names div a:hover~img {
  display: block;
}

.names div img {
  width: 40px;
  margin-top: 16px;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="names">
  <div><a class="name" href="#">Name</a><img src="https://picsum.photos/seed/picsum/200/300"></div>
  <div><a class="name" href="#">Name</a><img src="https://picsum.photos/seed/picsum/200/300"></div>
  <div><a class="name" href="#">Name</a><img src="https://picsum.photos/seed/picsum/200/300"></div>
  <div><a class="name" href="#">Name</a><img src="https://picsum.photos/seed/picsum/200/300"></div>
  <div><a class="name" href="#">Name</a><img src="https://picsum.photos/seed/picsum/200/300"></div>
  <div><a class="name" href="#">Name</a><img src="https://picsum.photos/seed/picsum/200/300"></div>
  <div><a class="name" href="#">Name</a><img src="https://picsum.photos/seed/picsum/200/300"></div>
</div>
```

As you can see only the hovered item is affected in height.

You can give every item a bigger height so the image won't overlap:

```css
.names {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
}

.names div {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  padding: 16px 0;
  height:70px;
  text-align: center;
}

.names div a {
  font-size: 16px;
  color: #25282e;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.names div a:hover {
  font-weight: 700;
}

.names div a:hover~img {
  display: block;
}

.names div img {
  width: 40px;
  margin-top: 16px;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="names">
  <div><a class="name" href="#">Name</a><img src="https://picsum.photos/seed/picsum/200/300"></div>
  <div><a class="name" href="#">Name</a><img src="https://picsum.photos/seed/picsum/200/300"></div>
  <div><a class="name" href="#">Name</a><img src="https://picsum.photos/seed/picsum/200/300"></div>
  <div><a class="name" href="#">Name</a><img src="https://picsum.photos/seed/picsum/200/300"></div>
  <div><a class="name" href="#">Name</a><img src="https://picsum.photos/seed/picsum/200/300"></div>
  <div><a class="name" href="#">Name</a><img src="https://picsum.photos/seed/picsum/200/300"></div>
  <div><a class="name" href="#">Name</a><img src="https://picsum.photos/seed/picsum/200/300"></div>
</div>
```